# Python tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Hi I have a little question about Label in tkinter.

When you use Label outside classes, you do something like

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text = "something", background = "something")
label.pack()
```

However, when it's inside a class and the code goes something like

import tkinter as tk

```
class Example(tk.Frame):

    COLOURS = [ "#f45", "#ee5", "#aa4", "#a1e433", "#e34412", "#116611",
                "#111 eeefff", "#3aa922191", "#abbabbaaa" ]

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent


        col = 1
        for colour in Example.COLOURS:
        #
        label = tk.Label(self, text=colour, background=colour)
        #
        label.grid(row=1, column=col)
        col += 1


def main():
root = tk.Tk()
ex = Example(root)
root.geometry("+300+300")
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but shouldn't it be rather like

```
label = tk.Label(self.parent, text=colour, background=colour)
```

since self.parent would correspond to root?
When I try to do that, I get an error and I only do when I have the
label.grid(...) line under it(I tried pack and it worked fine).

So I thought this code

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

wouldn't work either, but it actually worked fine.
So I'm confused. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should not be `self.parent`.

In the class example you give, the class is itself a frame. It is designed this way to make the example self-contained. By inheriting from `Frame` you can take all of the code in that class and put it anywhere in the GUI. You can think of the class and everything in it as a single custom widget. You could have multiple of these classes, and each one can be treated as a single GUI object.

To make that work, the class only ever puts widgets inside itself, not in its parent.

The entire purpose of using a sublcass of `Frame` is to act as a container for other widgets. If you don't plan on using it as a container for other widgets, there's no point in inheriting from `Frame`.

It is the equivalent of this, without classes:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(...)
label = tk.Label(frame, text = "something", background = "something")
label.pack(...)
```

If you wanted the class to put widgets in the parent, you would define the class like the following. Notice that it inherits from `object` rather than `Frame`:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        ...
        label = tk.Label(parent, ...)
```

Comment: Oh, so the class I made is automatically a frame because I inherited from the tk.Frame class? Or did initialising the Frame class inside ex.__init__ actually return a frame object?

Comment: Also, I actually forgot to mention that in the example, root(tk.Tk())is passed to the parent parameter(you probably knew it though).

Comment: Yes, it is a frame because you inherit from `Frame`.

Comment: And you are saying Label's first argument should be a frame not root(tk.Tk())?

Comment: @NamanJain: the first argument to `Label` can be anything you want. If you use the class method in the example you should use `self`, otherwise it's pointless to use the class. _the entire purpose of inheriting from Frame in that example is specifically to act as a container for the other widgets_.

Comment: K mate. But could you tell me the difference between frame and root?

Comment: `frame` is an instance of `Frame`, `root` is an instance of `Tk`. They are two different widgets.